# SSRS Filter greyed out

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]

I have a report with filters, If I select year (1st Filter) its works, but after the first selection the second filter Audits does not enable or is not clickable?

I'm not sure why this happens because I am new to SSRS. Not sure what to look for.
What I have done is checked my parameters and they look fine.

Comment: Try to add a defauklt value for the second parameter or change the order of the parameters (so that Audit goes first, then Year goes, then Protocols)

Comment: It is greyed out because it is waiting for some input, before it can run the query that populates the parameter choices.  Do you have the Audits parameter 'Available Values' set to a query?  If so, does that query need a specific year from the 'Year' selection?  Can it run with multiple years?