# Single User Has SSRS Parameters Greyed Out

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a user who sees the parameters in all of the SSRS reports she has access to, greyed out.  When I click on the report(s) they are not greyed out.  I've tried adding her specific login to both SSMS Security, with appropriate mappings as well as adding her login to the report/folder.  I'm totally stumped!

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 11.0.5058.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855800/ssrs-filter-greyed-out

Comment: what are these logins? are they through active directory or saved in any database?

Comment: Are your parameters query based? She may have access to the reports but not the data. Check her permissions on any table or view you're using.

Comment: A little more detail:  She is able to access the report parameters when she logs onto a different workstation.  When I log onto her workstation I don't have an issue.  So this means it's only her, only on that specific machine....

Comment: Try a different browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was related to the Compatibility Settings in IE.  I wanted to post the answer in case someone else is ever as stumped as myself.

Under Tools > Compatibilty View Settings in Internet Explorer, I added the server in which the reports are housed.

Thanks for all your help :)